# webpack typescript angular 2 settings based on environement

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have an angular service that needs to access 2 different url based on the npm environement but I cant figure out how to do this

lets say in dev (on my machine), I should have

```
    authenticate(login: string, pass: string): Observable < boolean > {
        return this.http.get('http://some_url')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    };
```

on the production it should be

```
    authenticate(login: string, pass: string): Observable < boolean > {
        return this.http.get('http://some_other_url')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    };
```

so I would like to set that url in the code depending on

```
process.env.npm_lifecycle_event
```

is it possible ?
how to achieve that ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

the define plugin should do the trick

https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin